# C++ Why am I not seeing output from cout?

Tags: c++, eclipse, cout

Given this little piece of code

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : prwe.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl; // prints Hello World
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles under Eclipse ,but nothing is presented in the Console window .

Any idea what did I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Keep a break point at the return statement or try taking input after cout.

Comment: Are you running this in the IDE, i.e., does the console window just close?  That would be expected behavior.

Comment: Try using getchar(); before the return 0; statement. This will keep the console open.

Comment: @EdS.: Yes ,Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers .

Comment: Computer is faster than the eye ;)

Comment: You should run console programs from a console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program runs, prints Hello World, and closes before you can see it.

add

```
 cin.get();
```

before the return 0; and it should be working fine. Then, you will have to hit enter to close the console.

What cin.get(); is doing is requiring user input to continue, and in this case continuing closes the program.

Comment: When I run this code from eclipse , it shows nothing . But when I debug the code with a breakpoint , then I see the output . Why is that ?

Comment: And before you get confused why `cin` doesn't work, a newline left in the buffer from something like `cin >> i` gets consumed by `cin.get()`, so it appears to do nothing, but it's actually extracting the left over newline.

Comment: The reason that happens is because the program prints hello world and closes after. The console will automatically close when you reach the end of main(), and adding a breakpoint prevents that, allowing you to see the output. The reason it shows nothing is the program is running so fast you don't see it.

Comment: @Snorf: This is really weird since this code also doesn't present anything : `//============================================================================
// Name        : xxzx.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout << "Hello World" << endl; // prints Hello World
 int y;
 cin >> y;
 return 0;
}
`

Comment: Try writing `cout << "Hello World! <<endl; system.("PAUSE")` This is a bad habit to get in to but it should show if there is an issue with your compiler. Also, is cin.get(); working?

Comment: @Snorf: Still doesn't work , any way to make the console stay open after the program terminates ? I've worked with C++ last year but moved to Java for a few months , but I do recall that nothing like that has ever happened to me . Maybe this is because of `minGW` ?

Comment: @ron, MinGW has always been great for me.